# Where I can find table compatibility websphere with versions of spring and hiberate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, websphere

Where I can find table compatibility websphere with versions of spring and hiberate?

There is application on spring + jpa(envers) deployed on websphere application server, and there are much error when I migrated from tomcat to this application server.

Does exist any doc or table of compatibility websphere versions( I use websphere 8.5.5.13) with versions of spring, jpa, hibernate ?

I used spring 4.3.13 and hibernate 4.0.1 now, but envers functions already not work

Comment: Does websphere prepackage spring or hibernate? I guess not, so this should not be an issue. If you can share errors we can help then

Comment: It might help if you can post some samples of the kinds of messages you're getting. I'm not aware of any kind of table of compatibility, but we are definitely using Spring 4.3.x with WebSphere 8.5.5.13. Can't speak to Hibernate.